# Node library slow to recompile on MacOS when installed through nvm

Tags: node.js, macos, webpack, nvm

I have a very strange issue that I cannot get to the bottom of. I am using node installed through nvm for a front end repo built using webpack.

On my previous mid-range laptop, the time between recompiles (after changes) was around 15 seconds. This was consistent across Windows (with WSL2) and Unbuntu, both running native.

I have recently switched to a Macbook Pro with better specs but now the time to recompile is **1 minute** and sometimes longer.

When I tried using node installed as a `.pkg` from the NodeJS website that issue is not there.

I added the `--progress` flag when launching webpack and saw that as soon as I saved a file it picked it up, however, it would stay at *optimizing chunks* for a very long time.

**Versions:**

- nvm: latest 0.36.0
- Node: 10.16.0
- Webpack: 3.12.0
- OS: tried on both Catalina and Mojave
- Repo: is private

I am perplexed as to what could be causing this; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could the package have been downloaded a precompiled module previously? Otherwise can you provide the node versions, mac versions and package.

Comment: Hi @Matt, thanks for commenting. The package was cloned from our private repo, then `npm ci` run inside it using the version of node specified in .nvmrc and then the `start` script was run. This process was done the same across the different OSes I used, only on Mac that the issue is present.